# PHP and AVS: Video comment form customization?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to modify a form on a framework, and I don't really know what's going on.

The form looks like this:

```
<form name="postVideoComment" id="postVideoComment" method="post" action="#">
                    <input type = "text" id = "user_handle" name = "user_handle" class="video_comment">
                <textarea name="video_comment" id="video_comment" cols="100" rows="5" class="video_comment"></textarea>
                <div id="post_message" class="post_message" style="display: none;">{t c='global.comment_empty'}</div>
                <div class="action"><span id="chars_left">1000</span> {t c='global.chars_left'}</div>
                <div class="action">
                    <input name="submit_comment" type="button" value=" {t c='global.post'} " id="post_video_comment_{$video.VID}" class="button" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear_left"></div>
            </form>
```

However, somehow the input with id user_handle is not passed to the form. This form submits to a file video_comment.php that behaves in a way that I cannot understand (for example it's using $filter->get('comment') to get the comment; where this 'comment' is coming I have no idea. But it's working really well for comments, except it's ignoring my user_handle:

```
    $data   = array('msg' => '', 'code' => '', 'vid' => 0, 'cid' => 0);
if ( isset($_POST['video_id']) && isset($_POST['comment']) ) {
    if ( $config['video_comments'] == '0' ) {
        $data['msg'] = 'Video comments are currently disabled!';
    } else {
        $spam   = false;
        if ( isset($_SESSION['v_comment_added']) ) {
            $delay  = intval($_SESSION['v_comment_added'])+30;
            if ( time() < $delay ) {
                $spam = true;
                $_SESSION['v_comment_added'] = time();
            }
        }

        $filter         = new VFilter();
        $uid            = '1';
        $vid            = $filter->get('video_id', 'INTEGER'); 
        $user_handle    = $_POST['user_handle'];
        $comment        = $filter->get('comment');
        var_dump($_POST);
        $sql            = "INSERT INTO video_comments ( VID, UID, comment, user_handle, addtime )
                           VALUES (" .$vid. ", " .$uid. ", '" .mysql_real_escape_string($comment). "', '" .mysql_real_escape_string($user_handle). "', '" .time(). "')";
        $conn->execute($sql);
```

Any help appreciated!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "VFilter" class may be cleaning the POST data to make sure that those data are only accessed via the $filter instance. Look at that class, I guess there is a mapping from POST variable names to the short ones like 'comment'.